# Datetime writes 1899-12-30: How to remove it?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm writing a python script to grab certain times from an excel spreadsheet and print them out to the console when the script is run. Here are the first few cells of the spreadsheet:

```
  A     B
1 #   Time
2 1  00:00:00
3 2  00:00:20
4 3  00:00:30
5 4  00:00:40
6 5  00:00:50
```

The first cell I'm pulling from always has the time 00:00:00. However, printing the data onto the console adds the date 1899-12-30 to the first value. All the other times don't have the date appended to them. How can I remove the date from the data that gets printed to the console?

```
times = []
times.append(sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value) #this is the value that gets 1899-12-30

for i in range(2, sheet.max_row):
     if (condition):
          times.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value) #these times come out fine

for i in times:
    print(i)
```

How can I make the first `times.append` line not print 1899-12-30?

Comment: can you provide the first lines of your excel file in order for us to help you?

Comment: check for null or blank values. Looks like it is the default date.

Comment: @cccnrc Sure, just did

Comment: The value attribute evaluates to a `datetime` object, with 1899-12-30 being the implied date with no other information available. (No solution yet, hence the comment instead of an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`times` is a list of `datetime` objects, which appear to default to 1899-12-30 in the absence of any other date information. You can extract a `time` object from each using the `time()` method.

```
times = []
times.append(sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value.time())

for i in range(2, sheet.max_row):
     if (condition):
          times.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value.time())

for i in times:
    print(i)
```

Comment: I notice that `cell` objects have a `base_date` property, although I couldn't figure out if there was a proper way to update that.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else may be able to give you a more general answer, but for your specific case (since you said it's always the same), just replace

`times.append(sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value)`

with

`times.append('00:00:00')`

Update: You should be able to just take the `time` portion of the datetime object provided by openpyxl:

```
times = []
times.append(sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value.time()) # or hardcode this cell value

for i in range(2, sheet.max_row):
     if (condition):
          times.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value.time()) 

for i in times:
    print(i)``
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just did that, and it looks fine on the console. However, I need to do some math with these times so I'm weary about hardcoding. Do you think it'll interfere if I need to subtract the printed value of ```00:00:00``` from a datetime value like ```00:01:08```?

Comment: @YasirC Got it. Check the update that might make subtracting better (and maybe even eliminate the need to hardcode).

Comment: That totally worked and solved my problem perfectly. Thank you for suggesting pandas. I thought it would be difficult to work with but that's clearly not the case. Thank you again!

Comment: openpyxl already handles the conversion to datetime object so no need for additional conversion.